# Lightning Components: How to get the new inline-Edit feature redered by force:recordView?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, app-builder

In my Lightning Component Markup, I have

```
<force:recordView recordId="{!v.recordId}" type="FULL"/>
```

Unfortunately it has no pencil-icons (the inline-edit successors) and it looks only like this:

[image]

What I would expect is, that it will look like that (output produced by the app builder Component "Record Detail"):

[image]

How we can get the new inline-editing in our own components?

Comment: Is this possible in current release, And did you acheived this in any other ways

Comment: Does anyone has solution for inline edit in force:recordView tag ?

Comment: @brahmajitammana  I've noticed, that in summer 17 now the pencil icons are show, but they do not work when clicked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going through some old unanswered questions and stumbled upon this. Going by your reputation, chances are high that you already figured this out by now, but I am still going to answer for those who end up here seeking an answer.

`force:recordView` component represents a ***read-only*** view of a record.

Record detail with inline editing can now be accomplished in a couple of ways:

> 1. force:recordEdit

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">

    <lightning:card>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <force:recordEdit aura:id="RecordEdit" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
            <lightning:button label="Save" onclick="{!c.save}"/>
        </p>
    </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

**Controller JS**

```
({
    save : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("RecordEdit").get("e.recordSave").fire();
    }
})
```

> 2. lightning:recordForm

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">

    <lightning:card>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning:recordForm 
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
                                  objectApiName="ThisObjectAPIName__c" 
                                  layoutType="Full" 
                                  columns="2"
                                  mode="edit"
                                  onsubmit="{!c.doSomething}" />
        </p>
    </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

Here is more info on [force:recordEdit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordEdit/documentation) and [lightning:recordForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation). Also related is [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/example), which allows one to include selected fields as opposed to the entire page layout.